# Uncaught ReferenceError: 'somevar' is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Am trying to insert some data into mysql through ajax call but while am trying to get the data from my form javascript throws me this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: anjelis is not defined" on the first variable

```
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>aloooooooooooooo!!!!!!!!!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
        setInterval(function(){$('#chatlog').load('logs.php');},1000);
        setInterval(function(){$('#user_list').load('user_list.php');},1000);
    });
    function submitChat(){
    var uname=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>;
    var msg=form.msg.value;
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById('chatlog').innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open('GET','insert.php?username='+uname+'&msg='+msg,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    </script>
</head>
```

The body

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ChatCY</a>
    </div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){echo '<a href="login.php">Login/Signin</a>';}else{
                echo'<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>';}?></li>
          </ul>         
      </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="chatlog" class="panel-body"></div>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div id="user_list" class="panel-body"></div>
 </div>  
 </div>
 </div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-8">
         <form class="form-inline">
         <form name="form" class="form-group" onsubmit="return false;">
        <input type="textarea" class="form-control" name="msg" style="width:90%;"<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            echo 'disabled="disabled" placeholder="You must be logged in to chat .."';}?>></input>            
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" name="send" <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
            echo 'disabled="disabled"';}?> onClick="submitChat();">send</button>
        </form>
        </form>
        </div>
     </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: change `var uname=<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>;` this to `var uname="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>";` and check please.

Comment: you forget to start session `session_start()` at the top of your page!!

Comment: Also, </input> isn't necessary.

Comment: @dll_onFire Can't you use jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the code 
`session_start()`,
well you can do  it another way, create a inpu tag in your html

`<input type='hidden' id='uname' value="<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>">`

in js
get your id like this

`var uname = $('#uname').val();`

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of issues in your code.

1. Quotes are missing in the variable. Add quotes here:

   ```
   var uname = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>";
   ```
2. <s>Session is not started. Start the session using:</s>

   ```
   session_start();
   ```
3. Try not to mix up both PHP and HTML. Keep it separate. Don't use `echo` to write the HTML tags.
4. No `<input />` has an ending tag, and there's no `<input type="textarea"`... It should be replaced with `<input type="text"`.
5. Use jQuery or some other awesome libraries for doing complex functions like AJAX calls or something. That makes your and dev's life easier, by providing functions for all the browsers and less clutter of code.

   ```
   $.ajax(function () {
       "url": "/",
       // Blah Blah
   });
   ```

Comment: @dll_onFire Oh great! Then fine.

Comment: now it says (form is not defined) for the next line which is var msg=form.msg.value;

Comment: @dll_onFire Can you please update the question with the **rendered HTML**? The one you get it on View Source?

Answer (score 0):

Missed the quotes -

```
 var uname= "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']?>";
 var form = $('form.form-group');
```

If it is

```
var uname = somevar;
```

`somevar` will be undefined.

You are not passing or defining `form` to the function or inside the function.

Comment: now it brings the error (form is not defined) to the next line which is var msg=form.msg.value;